# How can I make a switch using a MOSFET to control an input signal?

Tags: mosfet, switches, relay, high-side

I have a two channel relay module that takes 12 V to power. It also has two inputs, which take either 12 V or 0 V. On the other side of the module are the NC and NO and COM pins that I am connecting 12 V and my linear actuator.

When the relay module is provided with 12 V to both input pins, the motor does not move. When one or the other is low, it moves in the corresponding direction.

How would I use a MOSFET controlled by a microcontroller, to control whether the relay module inputs recieve a 12 V signal or a 0 V signal?

I used an N-channel MOSFET as a low side switch an attempt to make a switch, and while the relay module did operate, I know this is not correct (can’t say 100% why, something about the relationship of the voltage between the gate and drain I believe, but I also saw the voltage toggled between 12 and 7 rather than 12 and 0 which I need/expected.)

I am guessing that I need a P-channel MOSFET and that I could essentially just replace the N-channel without changing any of the other parts in the circuit, but I’m second guessing myself.

Components list:

- Relay module: [B00LW15F42](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LW15F42)
- Linear actuator: [L11TGF1000NB300-T-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L7XCSDW)
- [N-channel MOSFET](https://www.adafruit.com/product/355)
- [Microcontroller](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2590)

This setup sort of works, as I mentioned. I suspect it works due to the voltage threshold of the relay being something between the 7 and 12 V I see in this current setup, but I am at least reasonably confident that using an N-channel MOSFET in this manner is incorrect. I suspect I should be able to replace the N-channel MOSFET with a P-channel with 12 V to the drain, then source to the relay (exactly as it is with the N-channel)

[image]

Comment: What is the part number of the relay module?  The linear actuator?  The MOSFET?  The microcontroller?  How are they connected?  Use the schematic editor to show how you *want* them to be connected and show us a photograph of how you *actually* connected them.  Any part of the circuit design, part choice, or implementation could be at fault here and there is zero information to allow us to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: sorry for the lack of information, I thought the question was straightforward, but I have now updated. My apologies.

Comment: Please draw a schematic, not a wiring diagram of what you have. Name relevant node and refer to them instead of “other side of MOSFET”. Click on edit and then the schematic symbol. A schematic editor will open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I question the need for 12V or 0V at the relay module's input, to make it switch on or off. It seems likely to me that the module will accept 0V or 5V, and work perfectly fine.

You don't provide any information about that module, so I can't comment further on this. You will need to provide a link to the module's datasheet, or at least the module's model number and/or supplier.

In the unlikely case that you really do need a 12V signal to trigger the relay, then you would use an N-channel MOSFET like below left:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD9Czm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the right is a solution using a BJT instead of a MOSFET.

These transistors invert the signal. That is, a high (3V or greater) input at IN will produce 0V at OUT, and 0V at IN will produce +12V at OUT.

R2 and R5 keep IN low while the MCU output is high-impedance, prior to being configured in software. You may wish have this state default to high (OUT low), in which case you'd do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNPymc.png)</sup>

These modules claim to have opto-isolator inputs. If so, and these inputs are connected directly to an opto-isolator's LED, (perhaps through a resistor), then you need to alter your strategy a little. It's almost certainly possible to make this work, but the "right" way is highly dependent on the position of those jumpers; I suspect they control which side of the power supply (12V or 0V) the opto-isolator LEDs are connected to. Without more information, anything I suggest is risky, and could damage the transistor and/or relay module if I get it wrong. I prefer to remain silent until I have better information.

Comment: I'm sorry I have a clarifying question about the left schematic that I'm having trouble reading. It looks like the 12 volts after the resistor, connects to the input of the module and what I assume is the drain of the MOSFET. If the gate is open and power flows through the MOSFET, is that what would cause the input to be grounded despite the 12 volts appearing to be connected

Comment: @JordanKlaers Please refer to component names like R1, M1, R2 etc. That's what they are there for, to help communication. If M1 is "on", it effectively connects OUT directly to ground. That's why OUT would be 0V. When M1 is "off", it can be removed from the circuit because it's as if it's not there anyway, and the potential at OUT is gently coerced to +12V by R1. Then OUT would be +12V.

Comment: @JordanKlaers I notice the seller reports that the relay module will *not* operate from a 5V signal, which means you will indeed need some kind of interface to operate the module from an Arduino or Raspberry Pi output, or similar. However, the module has some kind of opto-isolator input, which means there's a good chance my circuits here will not work. There is insufficient information from the seller about the input circuitry on this module.

Comment: You answered exactly what I was curious about. It seems I'm lacking some fundamental understanding about why OUT would be 0v when M1 is on. That's something I can figure out on my own and I do understand your suggestion though and I appreciate your patience. I will try out your suggestion!

Comment: If this doesn't work, I suspect I may need a different relay since this one seems to be lacking extra information and has an uncommon 12 volt input signal requirement

Comment: @JordanKlaers You could always try to reverse engineer the design, and provide your results. That's hard work, but it might save you the trouble of re-ordering.

Comment: Looks like there's just a resistor on the board that's sized for the expected input voltage. You *may* be able to get away with high side switching with a P-channel MOSFET and a NPN.

Comment: I was able to get it working with the left schematic you posted. Thank you for the help! curious if you know, so I can do better in the future. I need to work on providing a proper schemtic (rather than a drawing) and listing the parts, but my post was closed after adding those two, what else should I have done differently/better?